# Firebase cloud functions throwing warning about "timestampsInSnapshots"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When I'm using firestore in cloud functions, I get the following error. How to fix that

```
  error:
    The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change
    AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
    To hide this warning and ensure your app does not break, you need to add the
    following code to your app before calling any other Cloud Firestore methods:
      const firestore = new Firestore();
      const settings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true};
      firestore.settings(settings);
    With this change, timestamps stored in Cloud Firestore will be read back as
    Firebase Timestamp objects instead of as system Date objects. So you will also
    need to update code expecting a Date to instead expect a Timestamp. For example:
      // Old:
      const date = snapshot.get('created_at');
      // New:
      const timestamp = snapshot.get('created_at');
      const date = timestamp.toDate();
    Please audit all existing usages of Date when you enable the new behavior. In a
    future release, the behavior will change to the new behavior, so if you do not
    follow these steps, YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution, install the latest firebase-functions and firebase-admin by going to the `functions` folder.

`npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save`

and then in your cloud function add something like below:

```
const firestore = admin.firestore();
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
firestore.settings(settings);
```